# How to create a table with cells not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to make a table to select the filters of an array with conditions here for example the beginning of the table for the filters (you cannot select client and user at the same time) :

[image]

to do this i create a table with id by cell :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    filter = {
        date: 0,
        client: 0,
        user: 0
    };

    $(".blank_row > td").click(function() {
       if (filter['date'] == 0 && $(this).attr('id') == 'date') {
            filter[$(this).attr('id')] = 1;
            $(this).addClass("bg-success");
        }
        else if (filter['date'] == 1 && $(this).attr('id') == 'date') {
            $(this).removeClass("bg-success");
            filter[$(this).attr('id')] = 0;
        }
    
        if (filter['client'] == 0 && filter['user'] == 0 && $(this).attr('id') != 'date') {
            filter[$(this).attr('id')] = 1;
            $(this).addClass("bg-success");
        } else if (filter['client'] == 1 || filter['user'] == 1) {
            $(this).removeClass("bg-success");
            filter[$(this).attr('id')] = 0;
        }
    
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        console.log(filter);
    });

});
```

```css
.blank_row {
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="graphTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="border" colspan="3">FILTER</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>DATE</th>
                    <th>CLIENT</th>
                    <th>USER</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="blank_row">
                    <td id="date"></td>
                    <td id="client"></td>
                    <td id="user"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

but if i want to add new cells i would be quickly lost with the code i already made. Do you have any other solution to do what I want more simply?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasClass` method of jquery to see if the `tds` have required class or not depending on that we can `addClass` or `removeClass` from any particular `tds`.

**Demo code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".blank_row > td").click(function() {
  //get td closest tr(index)
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    //getting cell no of td which is clicked
    var cell = $(this).index();
    //looping over the tr
    $('tbody > tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') ').each(function(cellIndex){
    
      var selectors = $(this).find("td:eq(" + cell + ")");
  //checking if the clicked td has some classes or not
   if (!(selectors.hasClass("bg-success")) && (selectors.hasClass("date"))) {
        //add
        selectors.addClass("bg-success");
      } else if (selectors.hasClass("date") && selectors.hasClass("bg-success")) {
        //removed
        selectors.removeClass("bg-success");
      }
 //checking if the client and user has bg-success or not
      if (!($(this).find(".client").hasClass('bg-success')) && !($(this).find(".user").hasClass('bg-success')) && !(selectors.hasClass("date"))) {
        //add
        selectors.addClass("bg-success");
      } else if ((($(this).find(".client").hasClass('bg-success')) || ($(this).find(".user").hasClass('bg-success'))) && !(selectors.hasClass("date"))) {
        //removed
        selectors.removeClass("bg-success");
      }

   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="graphTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border" colspan="3">FILTER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>CLIENT</th>
      <th>USER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="blank_row">
      <td class="date">a</td>
      <td class="client">b</td>
      <td class="user">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
      <td class="date">a1</td>
      <td class="client">b1</td>
      <td class="user">c1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
      <td class="date">a2</td>
      <td class="client">b2</td>
      <td class="user">c2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```